# counting the number of times a string appears within a group column

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following, where column b is a factor:

`df<-data.frame(a=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), b=c('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'cc'))`

I would like a column c that counts the number of times '1', '2', '3' or '4' has 'aa', so something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate(c = sum(b == "aa")) %>%
    ungroup()
```

In base R

```
transform(df, c = ave(+(b == "aa"), a, FUN = sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution which works for all combinations of levels in `a` and `b`. The idea is essentially you group by both the `a` and `b` columns (hence why they're in the third argument of the square brackets), then assign the number of rows in that combination (`.N`) to your new column (`c`).

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), b=c('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'cc'))
dt[, c := .N, .(b,a)]
dt
#>     a  b c
#>  1: 1 aa 2
#>  2: 1 aa 2
#>  3: 1 bb 1
#>  4: 2 aa 1
#>  5: 2 bb 1
#>  6: 2 cc 1
#>  7: 3 aa 3
#>  8: 3 aa 3
#>  9: 3 aa 3
#> 10: 4 aa 2
#> 11: 4 aa 2
#> 12: 4 cc 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` option with `rowsum`

```
df$c <- with(df, rowsum(+(b == "aa"), a)[,1][as.character(a)])
```